# How to fix Javadoc comment has parse error, Details: no viable alternative at input ' *' while parsing JAVADOC_TAG [NonEmptyAtClauseDescription]

Tags: java, javadoc, checkstyle, summary, maven-checkstyle-plugin

```
/**
* This method is used for ABC.
* @return
* @throw IOException when this exceptional condition occurs
*/
```

> [Error]:line:4- Javadoc comment at column 0 has parse error. Details:
> no viable alternative at input '     *' while parsing JAVADOC_TAG
> [NonEmptyAtClauseDescription]

Any idea why am I getting this error in the @throw line of Javadoc? How to fix this?

Comment: Because you didn't put anything for what the method returns and it is trying to parse the throw line as what is returned?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As described above, add a description to the return tag or remove it completely to resolve the error.

```
$ cat TestClass.java
public class TestClass {
    /**
    * This method is used for ABC.
    * @return desc
    * @throw IOException when this exceptional condition occurs
    */
    int method() throws IOException  {
        return 0; 
    }
}

$ cat TestConfig.xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE module PUBLIC
          "-//Puppy Crawl//DTD Check Configuration 1.3//EN"
          "https://checkstyle.org/dtds/configuration_1_3.dtd">

<module name="Checker">
    <property name="charset" value="UTF-8"/>

    <module name="TreeWalker">
        <module name="NonEmptyAtclauseDescriptionCheck" />
    </module>
</module>

$ java -jar checkstyle-9.0.1-all.jar -c TestConfig.xml TestClass.java
Starting audit...
Audit done.
```